# Lost all Facebook comments and likes when migrated website from Drupal to Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook, drupal, comments

Firstly sorry if this has been asked before, but I couldn't find the answer when I searched.

A client's website (www.gaystarnews.com) was recently migrated from a Drupal system to Wordpress system.  The URL structure has been maintained throughout, however we seem to have lost all the likes and comments we had on each article.

An example of this is:

www.gaystarnews.com/article/kallio-bohemia-meets-working-class-in-helsinkis-traditional-gay-quarter/

The old Drupal page can be viewed here:

test.gaystarnews.com/article/kallio-bohemia-meets-working-class-in-helsinkis-traditional-gay-quarter/

Originally when the drupal site was running off the www. subdomain (instead of the test.) that article had dozens of comments and a few thousand likes when in Drupal.

Is there a way to bring back these likes and comments, or are these gone for good?

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: did you switch from http to https?

Comment: _“The old Drupal page can be viewed here”_ – that URL results in a 404 only.

Comment: hi, no the site has never used https

Comment: Sorry, two example links are:
OLD
http://test.gaystarnews.com/article/14-disney-characters-you-had-no-idea-were-gay051013/

NEW
http://www.gaystarnews.com/article/14-disney-characters-you-had-no-idea-were-gay051013/

Comment: In your old site you had the `fb:admin` meta tag. Have you tried adding that one in the new page?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.
I figured this out in the end.
There was a trailing slash added by Wordpress permalinks. If I update the permalink to not use the '/' then the comments and likes reappear!